# Error! mysql.data.mysqlclient.mysqlexception(0x80004005)

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I want to remote connection with mysql . I connected in my localhost there is no error but when I want to connect remote I got this error.

I give permissions and change the firewall settings still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error number says: "Timeout expired." So how are you conecting? Do you have public IP or are you on localarea network? If not it's your problem. You can use something like hamachi.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you granted permissions to the user at the remote host you are trying to connect from?

`Grant ALL on *.* to 'user'@'remote_host' identified by 'password';`

that will give the user all permissions from the remote_host with a password.

Comment: can you telnet to 3306 on the remote host - that will help determine if it is network or password related.